# Current folder size

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

When browsing the current folder, while it's empty, `ls -lsa` still shows that `.` is ~168kB in size

Is there any specific data related to this folder why it is that much in size?

```
  4 drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data   4096 Dec 10 18:28 .
168 drwxrwxrwx 4 www-data www-data 167936 Dec 17 16:54 ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a [look](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-does-size-of-a-directory-mean-in-output-of-ls-l-command):

Question:

What does size of a directory mean in output of 'ls -l' command?

Answer:

> This is the size of space on the disk that is used to store the **meta
>   information for the directory** (i.e. the table of files that belong to
>   this directory). If it is i.e. 1024 this means that 1024 bytes on the
>   disk are used (it always allocate full blocks) for this purpose.

Also consider that when you e.g. remove a file from a directory , only its contents vanish. The **node remains in the directory structure**, only being marked as free.

Comment: This is true; in fact, if you really want to shrink the directory (no good reason though!), you will have to do: `rmdir DIR; mkdir DIR`, and then you will see the standard 4KB size, not before.